# how to find users country rank and also world rank?

Tags: mysql

how to find users country rank and also world rank?
please SQL query how to make

```
SELECT leaderboards.leaderboard_id, 
       users.name, 
       users.country, 
       users.points, 
       users.email, 
       leaderboards.score, 
       Find_in_set(users.points, (SELECT Group_concat(users.points ORDER BY 
                                         users.points DESC) 
                                  FROM   users))              AS world_rank, 
       Find_in_set(leaderboards.score, (SELECT 
       Group_concat(leaderboards.score ORDER BY 
       leaderboards.score DESC) 
                                        FROM   leaderboards)) AS rank, 
       leaderboards.created_date, 
       leaderboards.time_stamp 
FROM   users 
       INNER JOIN leaderboards 
               ON users.user_id = leaderboards.user_id 
WHERE  users.user_type = 2
```

above query, I have to get World rank But how to find country rank

Answer (score 0):

SELECT ld.leaderboard_id,c.name,c.points,c.world_rank,c.country_rank,ld.created_date,ld.time_stamp FROM leaderboards ld JOIN (SELECT FIND_IN_SET(b.points, ( SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( b.points ORDER BY b.points DESC) FROM users b)) AS world_rank, FIND_IN_SET(un.points, (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( un.points ORDER BY un.points DESC) FROM users un WHERE un.country=b.country)) AS country_rank,b.* FROM users un JOIN (SELECT u.name,u.user_type,u.country,u.points,u.user_id FROM users u)b ON b.user_id=un.user_id WHERE b.points!='' AND b.user_type=2)c ON c.user_id=ld.user_id ORDER BY c.points DESC[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ND3O8.png)

Comment: Please add some explanation and proper formatting to your answer such that others can learn from it